# Text alignment when all code is within html page

Tags: html, css

Hello to the community,

This is my first time asking, so I'm sorry if this was already asked before as I couldn't find anything searching by myself...

It's a basic yet complex question...

Anyway, I have a html page where there is also scripting and css. My goal is to align text verticaly in a specific DIV.

The style is defined this way:

```
#top-text{
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:5vh;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        height: 18vh;
        overflow: hidden;
/*      background-color:rgba(200,200,0,0.5); */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 5vh;
        width:calc(100vw - 20vh);
```

Then the DIV is given an ID

```
<div id="top-text">
    </div>
```

Then it's inserted through Inner HTML script command

```
document.getElementById("top-text").innerHTML = rssData.title ;
```

I want to vertically align this, but inserting "vertical-align:middle" and "display:table cell" haven't worked.

What would be a good way to do that?

I thank in advance anyone who might provide an answer.

Regards

Comment: try `display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;`

Comment: add `line-height` to css this also a good alternative to aligning text vertically.

Comment: Tamil, your answer worked. Thank you ^^. I can't find an option to mark your comment as an answer though :/.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried text-align? maybe if you'll add it in your css class for that div it will work if it's a text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

```js
document.getElementById("top-text").innerHTML = rssData.title ;
```

```css
#top-text{
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:5vh;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
background-color:rgba(200,200,0,0.5);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 10px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="top-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor si
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey Kumar. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, replacing the CSS in this case has made the text disappear. Would it help if I posted the entire page? It's not big (183 lines).

Answer (score 0):

Try text-align in css within the div tag